# yii cgridview displays summaryt text twice

Tags: php, yii

In my new yii application it displays as,

```
Displaying 1-3 of 1 result.|Displaying 1-3 of 3 results.

<div class="summary">Displaying 1-3 of 1 result.|Displaying 1-3 of 3 results.</div>
```

i have no clue how this part is replicated, this is my code.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'data-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'header' => 'No.',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 5%;'),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'type',
            'value' => '$data->getType($data->type)'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'incidentType',
            'value' => '$data->getIncidentType($data->incidentType)'
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adding this option inside your cgridview options:

```
'summaryText'=> "Displaying {start} - {end} of {count} result."
```